# Basic Report based on data

Tags: sql, postgresql, case-when

For each country, output its code, and the following information (in the given order) about its artists:
number of bands, number of artists who are not bands, total number of artists, percentage of bands,percentage of artists who are not bands.  Countries without artists do no appear in the output. Format percentages as decimal numbers with 0 decimal places.

Data format:
Artists
- name (string)
- type (either person or band)
- country (unique 3 digit code)

Countries
- code (unique 3 digit code)
- name (string)

---

Example:
Artists

```
Name |  Type  | Country
-----------------------
John    Band     qwe
Doe     Band     qwe
Mary    Person   qwe
Anon    Person   asd
```

Countries

```
Code  |  Name
--------------
qwe      Russia
asd      New Zealand
```

Expected Output:

```
Code | # of bands | # of artists not in band | total # of artists | % of bands | % of artists not in bands 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
qwe    2                1                            3                66             33
asd    0                1                            1                0              100
```

I just don't get how to keep track of everything and essentially like saving them so I can output all of them at once. I think I would be able to get this if it were just one country at a time, but if it contains multiple, I'm kind of lost.
Any resources on how to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use condition aggregate function in a `CTE` then do the calculation in main query.

**Schema (PostgreSQL v9.6)**

```
CREATE TABLE Artists(
   Name VARCHAR(50),
   Type VARCHAR(50),
   Country VARCHAR(50)
);


INSERT INTO Artists VALUES ('John','Band','qwe');
INSERT INTO Artists VALUES ('Doe','Band','qwe');
INSERT INTO Artists VALUES ('Mary','Person','qwe');
INSERT INTO Artists VALUES ('Anon','Person','asd');

CREATE TABLE Countries(
   Code VARCHAR(50),
   Name VARCHAR(50)
);



INSERT INTO Countries VALUES ('qwe','Russia');
INSERT INTO Countries VALUES ('asd','New Zealand');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
WITH CTE AS (
 SELECT Code,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN Type ='Band' THEN 1 END) BandCnt,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN Type <> 'Band' THEN 1 END) NotBandCnt,
        COUNT(Country) CountryCnt
 FROM Artists a 
 join Countries c on a.Country = c.Code
 GROUP BY Code
)
SELECT Code,
       BandCnt "# of bands",
       NotBandCnt "# of artists not in band",
       CountryCnt "total # of artists",
       BandCnt * 100.0  / CountryCnt  "% of bands",
       notBandCnt * 100.0  / CountryCnt  "% of artists not in band" 
FROM CTE;
```

**Result**

```
| code | # of bands | # of artists not in band | total # of artists | % of bands             | % of artists not in band |
| ---- | ---------- | ------------------------ | ------------------ | ---------------------- | ------------------------ |
| asd  | 0          | 1                        | 1                  | 0.00000000000000000000 | 100.0000000000000000     |
| qwe  | 2          | 1                        | 3                  | 66.6666666666666667    | 33.3333333333333333      |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kTkxp6K4H5CxBjkVgGSXVG/3)

Comment: How can I tailor this to if there's more than 3 countries, because of CASE WHEN Country = 'qwe', or would this work for more than 3 countries?   
 Thanks

Comment: You can try to use `IN` instead of `=`   https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kTkxp6K4H5CxBjkVgGSXVG/2

Comment: This means I would need to create a list of countries beforehand, assuming I don't know what countries the data contains? Thanks

Comment: @AnonLi Ok I see I edit my answer  https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kTkxp6K4H5CxBjkVgGSXVG/3

Comment: oh weird, your code seems to work fine in this example, but when I did it on my other database, the Count for BAND just displays 0 even though there are bands. However, when I deleted the CASE WHEN stuff and just had COUNT(TYPE='Band'), the count for Band is no longer just 0. Thanks!